# Tkinker Frame with Pack

Tags: python, tkinter

I have only been working with tkinter for a few months.  I wrote some code
using 'Frame' with 'Grid' with no problem. I just started trying to use 'Pack'
and am having a issue with this error:  AttributeError: 'Frame' object has no attribute 'frame1'.

What am i doing wrong?

### Code:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.title("Spin Box")
root.resizable(0,0)

frame1=Frame(root).frame1.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
frame2=Frame(root).frame2.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)

labe11=Label(frame1).labeL1.pack()
label2=Label(frame2, text="How many Ticket?", font="bold").label2.pack()

button1=Button(frame2, text="Get Tickets", font="bold", command=runcode).button1.pack()
button2=Button(frame2, text=" Close ", font="bold", command=subwin.destroy).button2.pack()

sp1=Spinbox(frame2, from_='1', to='5', bd=2, bg="white", state='readonly', relief=SUNKEN)
sp1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./tkerr3.py", line 7, in 
>       frame1=Frame(root).frame1.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
>   AttributeError: 'Frame' object has no attribute 'frame1'

Comment: Start with changing `labeL1` to `label1`

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a wrong idea about how to call `pack`.

```
frame1 = Frame(root).frame1.pack(....)
```

A `Frame` object doesnt have a property `frame1`, instead you want to call pack on the next line, once the Frame object has been bound to your variable.

```
frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.pack(....)
```

Same goes for all other 'packed' widgets.

You also have a typo waiting in the wings

```
labe11=Label(frame1).labeL1.pack()
```

Make it

```
label1=Label(frame1)
label1.pack()
```

A basically corrected version of your code here, with callbacks stubbed out.

```
from tkinter import *

def dummy(): pass

root=Tk()
root.title("Spin Box")
root.resizable(0,0)

frame1=Frame(root)
frame1.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
frame2=Frame(root)
frame2.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)

labe11=Label(frame1)
labe11.pack()
label2=Label(frame2, text="How many Ticket?", font="bold")
label2.pack()

button1=Button(frame2, text="Get Tickets", font="bold", command=dummy)
button1.pack()
button2=Button(frame2, text=" Close ", font="bold", command=dummy)
button2.pack()

sp1=Spinbox(frame2, from_='1', to='5', bd=2, bg="white", state='readonly', relief=SUNKEN)
sp1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```